# glibc malloc's chunk size data_header

Tags: c, malloc, glibc

Does the glibc's malloc chunk size have an extra bit set when it's in use?
The reason I'm asking is because I wrote a simple test case where I allocate several chunks and then print its size from the lower 8bytes offset from the base pointer to each chunk (as described in the source code).
Like so:

```
int main(void)
{
 int* p1 = malloc(_p1);
 int* p2 = malloc(_p2);
 int* p3 = malloc(_p3);

 printf("p3: %p %d\n",p3,_p3);
 printf("p2: %p %d\n",p2,_p2);
 printf("p1: %p %d\n",p1,_p1);

 printf("p3-2: %5dd %5xh\n", *(p3-2), *(p3-2));
 printf("p2-2: %5dd %5xh\n", *(p2-2), *(p2-2));
 printf("p1-2: %5dd %5xh\n", *(p1-2), *(p1-2));

 printf("p1 %p %p\n p-2\n", p1, p1-2);

 printf("\n");
 return 0;
}
```

An example output; however, shows the size to always be 1byte extra. so my question is, where does this extra byte come from?

```
p3: 0x1d4e0b0 64
p2: 0x1d4e060 64
p1: 0x1d4e010 64

p3-2:    81d    51h
p2-2:    81d    51h
p1-2:    81d    51h

p1 0x1d4e010 0x1d4e008
```

I thought that maybe there is a bit set when the chunk is in use, but even if I free the chunk the look up its size with the correct offset, it still shows same size.

Could anyone elaborate as to what I'm doing wrong or where this byte is coming from?

Thanks,

Comment: After `free`, the chunk is merged with an adjacent free chunk so the bytes that were formerly a header are now just interior junk.

Comment: ok, but do you have an answer as to why the size of a used chunk has an extra byte? As far as the free chunks. Glibc's malloc keeps everything up to 128k in bins, a 32bytes or 64 byte free chunk, as I understand it, should go into the appropriate bin of the same size , no? So shouldn't the appropriate elements be set to the same size and any "in-use" bit reset to 0?

Comment: Maybe this answer can relate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36734496/296549