# How does malloc know if an object was modified after being freed?

Tags: memory, memory-management, malloc

I have a complex program that uses Java code for a UI and C/C++ code for a simulator backend.  The Java code calls the C code via JNI.

Now, I'm getting this error:

```
java(14611,0x11dd8e000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fb95c1b4e08: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

I know there is some sort of memory problem in my code, but my question is:

How does *malloc* know that memory was modified after it was freed?  What is it doing that it can detect this?  Is it creating a checksum of memory before deallocating it then saving that checksum and validating the memory hasn't changed during the next allocation?

In particular, I set the recommended breakpoint and the above error happened on a memory deallocation.  So if my above assumption about how things are working is correct, then why is this detection happening on deallocation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, malloc implementations allocate a header in front of address returned to the caller. Sometimes they have a trailer as well that is used to detect overruns.

It sounds lie your free() is running a checksum of some sort on the block then storing that value in the header.

Your malloc implementation is then examining the block, recalculating the checksum, and finding the data has been modified.

It is most likely that malloc is trying to reuse a block that has been allocated and freed once already. It is less likely that malloc is doing a scan of all freed blocks.

Comment: Thanks! Here's another SO question that I found after I read your answer and saw that malloc creates theses headers... depending on the implementation.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717296/malloc-header-contents