# Is my program leaking memory?

Tags: c

I'm learning C and to to get a better grasp of some topics in a fun way, I wrote something that does successive allocations/deallocations. Here's the code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main( void )
{
    uint16_t i, j, k, l, m, n = 10, z = 25;
    int64_t ******v;

    while ( n-- )
    {
        v = malloc( sizeof( int64_t ***** ) * z );

        for ( i = 0; i < z; ++i )
        {
            v[ i ] = malloc( sizeof( int64_t **** ) * z );

            for ( j = 0; j < z; ++j )
            {
                v[ i ][ j ] = malloc( sizeof( int64_t *** ) * z );

                for ( k = 0; k < z; ++k )
                {
                    v[ i ][ j ][ k ] = malloc( sizeof( int64_t ** ) * z );

                    for ( l = 0; l < z; ++l )
                    {
                        v[ i ][ j ][ k ][ l ] = malloc( sizeof( int64_t * ) * z );

                        for ( m = 0; m < z; ++m )
                            v[ i ][ j ][ k ][ l ][ m ] = malloc( sizeof( int64_t ) * z );
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for ( i = 0; i < z; ++i )
        {
            for ( j = 0; j < z; ++j )
            {
                for ( k = 0; k < z; ++k )
                {
                    for ( l = 0; l < z; ++l )
                    {
                        for ( m = 0; m < z; ++m )
                            free( v[ i ][ j ][ k ][ l ][ m ] );

                        free( v[ i ][ j ][ k ][ l ] );
                    }
                    free( v[ i ][ j ][ k ] );
                }
                free( v[ i ][ j ] );
            }
            free( v[ i ] );
        }
        free( v );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm on Windows x64, so pointer size is 8 bytes. So if my math is right, the program should allocate ~2.03GB of RAM.
But in reality, it allocates ~2.7GB.
Also, the memory consumption increases by ~2MB after each iteration of the `while` loop.
And lastly, after the 8th iteration of the `while` loop, after all `free()`s, taskmgr still shows the program holding ~1.4GB of RAM, even though next allocations still top at ~2.7GB normally.

The questions are: is my math wrong? What about the additional ~2MB at each iteration? And the un`free()`d ~1.4GB of RAM? What's happening?

Comment: `int64_t ******v;` No. Just no. Not even as a learning exercise.

Comment: This....this takes me to a dark, dark place.

Comment: @John3136 Oh please, this is a perfect learning illustration of the underlying concepts. It's not about design or any other sw engineering topic.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername 6 levels of indirection in C ? We'll have to agree to disagree.

Comment: @John3136 Yes. Nobody claims this to be a production code.

Comment: @John3136 `in a fun way`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it is not leaking memory.

When you request x bytes with malloc, more than x bytes are used up, in  part to create space for memory headers, as well as any other bookkeeping. See this answer for more details [Malloc header contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717296/malloc-header-contents)

Comment: That explains the extra memory usage. Any idea about the other issues?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I would guess that RAM is unfreed because your malloc blocks cause the process to request more memory from the O/S, but when you free your memory blocks those blocks remain part of the process memory space, they are not necessarily returned to the operating system when you free them, those blocks remain part of the memory space and will be reused by your program if/when you request more memory later.

Comment: So you're saying this is some kind of "lazy" memory deallocation optimization by the OS?

Comment: No, there is nothing lazy about it, and it's not the O/S, it's the standard C runtime, but the O/S as well may be managing memory pages in ways that are not obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Answer:  no.  I ran your code under linux (with `n` set to 2 so it wouldn't take forever, admittedly):

```
£ valgrind --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes ./CMakeHelloWorld
==4213== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4213== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4213== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4213== Command: ./CMakeHelloWorld
==4213==
==4213==
==4213== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4213==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4213==   total heap usage: 10,172,526 allocs, 10,172,526 frees, 2,034,505,200 bytes allocated
==4213==
==4213== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==4213==
==4213== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4213== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

What you are doing should **never ever** happen btw.  Matrixes are typically allocated in a block `int *pMap = (malloc(x*y*sizeof(int))` and for anything else there are better tools for managing references.  Anything past `**` is almost certainly complete foolishness.

Comment: Thanks. And I know I shouldn't do this and what not. It was just for fun. I know how expensive mem. alloc. calls are.

Comment: @KaeLL - The issue is less how expensive it is, and more how rapidly incomprehensible use of data structured like this becomes.  I get it though.  Just for fun :)